# What are the differences between method class methods and prototype?

Tags: javascript, methods, prototype

see below the sample code and please explain my question below I mention!

```js
class User{
  constructor(email,name){
    this.email = email;
    this.name = name;
  }
  
  login(){
    console.log(this.email);
  }
}

var u1 = new User("dil@gm.com","dil");
u1.login();
```

---

```js
function User(email,name){
  this.email = email;
  this.name = name;
}

User.prototype.login = function(){
  console.log(this.email);
}

var u2 = new User("dil@gm.com","dil");
u2.login();
```

**what is the difference between above them two type of coding? I mean normal method declaration and prototype deceleration when both instance access those methods?**

Comment: Your code has syntax errors, can you please update your code

Comment: `User.prototype.login` method definition should be outside the object definition body.

Comment: Prototypes are the original syntax for defining classes in JavaScript. EcmaScript 6 added `class` declarations, which are mostly just new syntax for the same thing.

Comment: So both these codes are equivalent, they're just the new syntax and old syntax.

Comment: would both of methods add prototype object or not? and which is the new syntax and old syntax? can you explain briefly?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing.

JavaScript didn't originally have the concept of a Class, for OOP in JavaScript, the prototype-based approach was implemented.

Since ESX (can't remember exactly), the concept of a Class was introduced, essentially wrapping the prototype-based syntax, into a more popular Class-based syntax that developers are usually used to using in different languages.

I'd encourage using the new syntax, as it's generally more readable and (for me at-least) makes more sense when working with objects in JavaScript.

JavaScript implemented a similar concept when bringing us async/await, wrapping the old `Promise.resolve|.reject` with a synchronous feeling API, JavaScript is full of syntax sugar and hacky workarounds to provide similar support as other languages.

Answer (score 0):

The answer here is there isn’t one. These do effectively the same thing, it’s only a question of whether ES6 class syntax was used.

Please follow this for more details: https://www.toptal.com/javascript/es6-class-chaos-keeps-js-developer-up

Also, If anyone want more details about ES5 vs ES6 or javascript concepts. You can refer my PPT on some topics: 
https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1Rf_Ln2F-qmb3yrsTSrOnXbzqeTpOFhK72MHDhLOIRC8/edit#slide=id.p

Thanks!