# Proper way to export functions in Typescript (cloud functions)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-cloud-functions

So I'm new to cloud functions and after mixing it up with various tutorials and examples, I ended up with index.ts code like such:

```
exports.createFoo = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const fooCollection = admin.firestore().collection('foo');
```

Now, I ran into another example and I'm confused...

```
export const createFoo = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const fooCollection = admin.firestore().collection('foo');
```

should I do it like this instead? What's the difference? What's better practice?

Comment: Either one works equally well.  Choose what you prefer.  The second option is more idiomatic typescript, in my experience.  The first option is more classic javascript.

Comment: Doug, it's not JS vs TS idioms, it is ECMAScript modules vs CommonJS style modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the difference? What's better practice?

Go for what you find is more readable, JavaScript is a very flexible language that supports different ways of expressing yourself through code.

TypeScript adopts ES6+ style syntax, so it may be more *proper* to use `export const` opposed to `exports.`, it doesn't *really* matter though. It should come down to your preference and/or code-style/guidelines.

I wrote about a similar thing https://stackoverflow.com/a/61691978/2932298 to emphasize the different ways of doing things.